# How to compile and run c program using exec command in php?

Tags: php, linux

When I run

```
<?php
echo exec('whoami');
?>
```

It works fine, even for other single word command

but for `exec('gcc -o a hello.c');` it does not create object file a.

Or when I try `exec('./a');` with precreated object file, it does not make any change. No error no notification!

Any help is appreciable!

Comment: Try specifying full paths to your `hello.c` and `a`.

Comment: Also depends if you have privileges to use gcc from your user is it your server or a web hosting ?

Comment: @AleksG: I tried with exec('gcc -o /opt/lampp/htdocs/a /opt/lampp/htdocs/hello.c'); but no chage!

Comment: Get information in error log file. You might have permission restrictions.

Comment: No errors? Of course: you are ignoring `exec()`'s optional arguments and return value, where errors would normally be reported. You're also discarding stderr.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar how to check error log?

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
Add these lines in beginning of code and run again.

Answer (score 3):

Basic reference:

- [`exec()` manual page](http://php.net/exec)
- [Bash redirections](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) (applies to most other shells)

With those elements, it's straightforward to obtain error messages:

```
<?php

exec('gcc -o a hello.c 2>&1', $output, $return_value);

echo ($return_value == 0 ? 'OK' : 'Error: status code ' . $return_value) . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Output: ' . PHP_EOL . implode(PHP_EOL, $output);
```

E.g., I get this in my (Windows) computer:

```
Error: status code 1
Output: 
"gcc" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
```

Comment: what would be the values of $output and $return_value?

Comment: Pardon? Are you asking me to guess what the output would be in your computer?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `shell_exec()` in PHP:

`shell_exec('gcc -o a hello.c');` should work

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that the user account of your web server doesn't have write access to the directory. You can determine the account name by running `whoami` from within php.

```
exec('whoami', $output);
echo $output[0];
```

I don't know exactly what output you're going to get from that, but let's say it's `www-data` which is what I see on Ubuntu.

Now, if you look at the permissions of the web root directory, you'll probably find that it's owned by another account, maybe *root*, and the permissions are `rwxr.xr.x` so only *root* has access.

One way to give *www-data* write access is to make it the owner:

```
chown www-data .
```

Alternatively you can set the group to *www-data* and make sure that group has write access.

```
chgrp www-data .
chmod 775 .
```

Worst case you can give everybody write access, but I wouldn't recommend this unless nothing else works.

```
chmod 777 .
```

Ideally, you should really create a separate directory with write access, and limit any output to there rather than changing the permissions on the web root directory. But you can start with the root first and make sure this really is the problem before you go to too much effort.